# How do I access request arrays within arrays

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I have the following request;

```
Collection {#278
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "id" => 631
    "name" => "OIL, FILTER O.E.M."
    "partno" => "235-00"
    "oemnumber" => "16099 003"
    "stock" => 0
    "price" => "30"
    "qty" => 1
    "total" => 30
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "id" => 23
    "name" => "SPEEDOMETER"
    "partno" => "122-"
    "oemnumber" => "25005 1013"
    "stock" => 0
    "price" => "276"
    "qty" => 1
    "total" => 276
  ]
]
1 => array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "description" => "Oil change"
    "hours" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "description" => "Tune up"
    "hours" => "2"
  ]
]
2 => array:15 [
  "id" => 1
  "custId" => 9046
  "bikeId" => 5238
  "trans" => "yes"
  "transDetails" => "call cab"
  "policies" => "Yes"
  "locker" => "1"
  "lockerContents" => "stuff"
  "estimate" => "Yes"
  "oldparts" => "Yes"
  "status" => "Pending"
  "created_by" => null
  "created_at" => "2016-05-19 14:40:59"
  "updated_by" => null
  "updated_at" => "2016-06-08 09:06:58"
]
]
}
```

I am getting this through;

```
$collection = collect($request->all());
```

How should I go about accessing the attributes in these arrays?  I have tried pluck with no joy.  I suspect I could do a loop over them but with no array_expression for the arrays do I need to use the index?

Comment: You have an easy way to do this: `$request->input('fieldname');` of course using the proper field name as string.

Comment: right, but in the case of that input being one of multiples in a sub array, I get NULL.  For example with description: $description = $request->input['description'];  Arrays 0 and 1 in the above example are likely to contain multiple arrays in most cases.

Comment: Would you post your form code in a pastebin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EWCFdwR7

Comment: This is the http post from my Angular controller.

Comment: woParts and woLabours are arrays, workorder is an object.

Comment: What is the output of `dd($request->all())` ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xVyAFvMp

Comment: alariva thanks for the help.  I have decided to submit the form in 3 parts to avoid this mess.

Comment: Now, I get it, since you are posting an array, why dont you use `list()` constructor to assign directly to variables?